# Invoke a method of caller from callee on the caller object

Tags: c#

Let's say a scenario as below:

Assembly A1 is a windows application and has a class named C1 which has two methods M1 and M11.
Assembly A2 is a dll and has a class named C2 which has a method named M2.
A1 has a reference to A2, but not vice versa.

We are calling C2.M2() in C1.M1().

Now in method C2.M2(), I want to call C1.M11(), on the exact object which is calling C2.M2(), but I don't want to pass object of C1 to C2.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Thanks all for your replies.

[**Edit**]
But I want to know if there is an approach to do this via other technology, such as reflection, etc., instead of change signature of method. Thanks!

Comment: Over which codes do you have control? Can you alter both implementaions (A1 and A2) ?

Comment: This is what delegates are for.

Comment: Sounds like Visitor-Pattern or at least a "Callback". In that case you would not pass a reference of type C1 but an interface or delegate method which includes Func<T> or Action.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can pass a Function or Action parameter.

It's a type that allows to point toward some code defined by the caller, so your dll doesn't have to know anything about your calling application.
You just have to define the signature of the code you want to pass (ie return type and parameter types)

If the code have a return value, it's a Function :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

If the code have no return value, it's an Action :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain? While link-only answers are discouraged, this isn't *wrong* ...

Comment: @Fildor I didn´t say it´s whrong, but of low quality, not whrong but bad. And *this* is an acceptable reason to downvote also.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's true. I just like to give very low rep Users a chance and tell them how to improve ..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a design-flaw to me. When `C1` depends on `C2` and `C2` itself needs `C1` you have some circular dependency. As you don´t have access to `C1` within `C2` you can´t even pass a reference of the one to the other.

You have two ways to resolve these dependencies:

Inject a delegate to the instance of `C2`:

```
var c1 = new C1();
var c2 = new C2(c1.M11);
```

With

```
class C2
{
    private readonly Action<MyType> Method;
    public C2(Action<MyType> method)
    {
        this.Method = method;
    }

    // ...
    M2()
    {
        // call the delegate
        this.Method(instanceOfMytype);
    }
}
```

Another approach was to extract an interface of `C1` in a third assembly and pass that instance to `C2`.

```
interface MyInterface { 
    void M11(MyType) { ... }
}
// ...
var m = c1 as MyInterface;
var c2 = new C2(m);
```

Now within `C2` you can easily call the interface-method `M11` without relying on `C1`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to have the interface in Assembly A2? (I am referring to the last snippet)